# Validity of a statement on a function being infinitely differentiable at a point

Tags: real-analysis

Thinking about a problem, i had got this idea which appears true, but i feel it is a direct consequence of a well known theorem, the name of which i would like to ask here.

The idea can be put in the form of a theorem as below.

If a function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is infinitely differentiable at a point $x = x_o$ then given any arbitrarily large $r \in \mathbb{N}$ we can find an $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is $\mathcal{C}^r$ in the interval $(x_o-\epsilon,x_o+\epsilon)$.

I'd like to know the validity of this statement and if it is valid, from which theorem does it follow ?

Comment: What is your definition of being infinitely differentiable at a point?

Comment: This is valid, essentially by definition, so it is very unlikely to have a name.  For example, the second derivative of $f$ at $a$ is defined to be the limit as $h$ approaches $0$ of $(f'(a+h)-f'(a))/h$. For this limit to exist, $f'$ must exist in a neighborhood of $a$.

Comment: @Plop : by infinitely differentiable at a point $x_0$ i mean $f$ has derivatives of all orders at the point $x = x_o$.

Comment: And what is the definition of having a derivative of order $k$ at a point?

Comment: @Plop : I am not able to get what you intend to ask. Anyway let $f^1(x)$ be the derivative of $f(x)$, and $f^2(x)$ be the derivative of $f^1(x)$, then the second order derivative of $f(x)$ at $x = x_0$ is given as $f^2(x_o)$.

Comment: @Rajesh: I think he's trying to get you to write the formal definition (with epsilons) so you can see that the answer is very straightforward.

Comment: @Plop,@user6312,@Josh : I am unable to see how the validity is straightforward.

Comment: Not all functions are differentiable, so that's not a definition. I am trying to get you to realize that you cannot define the $k+1$th derivative of $f$ at $x_0$ unless $f^{(k)}$ is defined on a neighborhood of $x_0$.

Comment: @Plop : I agree, but how does that imply the validity of the statement in question ?

Comment: If $f$ is $k$ times differentiable on $]x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon[$, it is $\mathcal{C}^{k-1}$ on that interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original post seems to be generating an excessively long string of comments. I will try to explain things using the more generous editing facilities of the Answers format.

Take any function $g(x)$.  Let us think about what we mean when we write
$$\lim_{x \to a}\ g(x)=b$$
Very crudely, we mean that whenever $x$ is close enough to $a$ (but not necessarily equal to $a$), $g(x)$ is close to $b$.  In order for the phrase  "$g(x)$ is  close to $b$" to have meaning, $g(x)$ must exist, that is, $g(x)$ must be defined at $x$, it must make sense at $x$.  So we conclude that if $\lim_{x\to a} \ g(x)=b$, then in particular $g(x)$ must make sense, must be a number, for all $x$ in some interval about $a$, except possibly at $x=a$.

Now let us look at derivatives.  In general, denote the $n$-th derivative of $f$ by $f^{(n)}$ (the $0$-th derivative of $f$ is defined to be $f$).

The $(k+1)$-th derivative of $f$ at $a$ is defined as follows.
$$f^{(k+1)}(a)=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f^{(k)}(x)-f^{(k)}(a)}{x-a}$$

Look at this definition.  It mentions $f^{(k)}(a)$, so in particular, in order for $f^{(k+1)}(a)$ to exist, the very **meaning** of $f^{(k+1)}(a)$ **forces** $f^{(k)}(a)$ to exist. Also, the limit could not exist unless $f^{(k)}(x)$ existed for all $x$ close enough to $a$ but not equal to $a$.  So if $f^{(k+1)}(a)$ exists, then $f^{(k)}(x)$ must exist for all $x$ close enough to $a$, including $x=a$.

To sum up, analysis of the very definition (meaning) of differentiation shows that if $f$ is $k+1$ times differentiable at $a$, then $f$ must be $k$ times differentiable in some neighbourhood of $a$.

Comment: On the other hand, there are functions $f$ such that for any $n$, there is a polynomial $P$ of degree $n$ such that $|f(x) - P(x)| = O(|x|^{n+1})$ as $|x| \to 0$, just as if $f^{(k)}(0)$ existed for all $k$. Yet $f$ need not be differentiable at any $x \ne 0$.

Comment: @Hans Engler: Indeed, the definition of differentiability at a point could have been, and perhaps should have been, different from what it is.  But in any case, one is ordinarily interested mainly in differentiability in an interval.